# Spark Dataframe: Representing Schema of MapType with non homogeneous data types in StructType values

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to create a StructType schema to pass to the from_json API in order to parse a column stored as a JSON string. The JSON data contains a Map that has String keys and values of type struct, but the schema of each struct depends on the key.

Consider this JSON example where the "data" column is a Map with values `name` and `address` and the schema of each value is different:

```
{
  "data": {
    "name": {
      "first": "john"
    },
    "address": {
      "street": "wall",
      "zip": 10000
    }
  }
}
```

For key "name", the struct value has a single member field "first". For key "address", the struct value has two member fields "street" and "zip".

Can the "data" column be represented as a `MapType[StringType, StructType]` in a Spark dataframe?

1. Does Spark handle a Map[String, Struct] where the structs are non-homogeneous?
2. If yes, please share an example of a StructType schema representing a dataframe with schema `MapType<String, StructType>` where the StructType is non-homogeneous.

**EDIT**: To add another example of such data which has a Map[String, Struct] where the Struct is not of the same schema throughout the values of the Map, consider the following:

```scala
case class Address(street: String, zip: Int)
case class Name(first: String)
case class Employee(id: String, role: String)
val map = Map(
  "address" -> Address("wall", 10000),
  "name" -> Name("john"),
  "occupation" -> Employee("12345", "Software Engineer")
)
```

As you can see, the values of the map differ in their schema - Address, Name and Employee are all different case classes and their member fields are also different.

You can think of this kind of data coming from a JSON file where a map is allowed to have any arbitrary type of value across keys, and there is no restriction on all the values being of the same type. In my case I will have values that are all structs but the schema of each struct depends on the map key.

Comment: Could you please share more data sample? I'm trying to figure out what kind of non-homogeneous your data is

Comment: @Kafels I added more data, let me know if that doesn't help

Comment: I did an answer, please check it and in case of any error of Scala pattern, fix it for me, because this is the first time that I made a code in Scala

Answer (score 1):

You can read your JSON column and parse the schema dynamically:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, from_json}
import spark.implicits._


val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("""{"data":{"name":{"first":"john"},"address":{"street":"wall","zip":10000},"occupation":{"id":"12345","role":"Software Engineer"}}}"""),
  ("""{"data":{"name":{"first":"john"},"address":{"street":"wall","zip":10000}}}"""),
)).toDF("my_json_column")

val rows = df.select("my_json_column").as[String]
val schema = spark.read.json(rows).schema

// Transforming your String to Struct
val newDF = df.withColumn("obj", from_json(col("my_json_column"), schema))

newDF.printSchema
// root
//  |-- my_json_column: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- obj: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- address: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |-- street: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |-- zip: long (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- name: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |-- first: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- occupation: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |-- role: string (nullable = true)

newDF.select("obj.data", "obj.data.occupation.id").show(false)
```

Output

```
+---------------------------------------------------+-----+
|data                                               |id   |
+---------------------------------------------------+-----+
|{{wall, 10000}, {john}, {12345, Software Engineer}}|12345|
|{{wall, 10000}, {john}, null}                      |null |
+---------------------------------------------------+-----+
```